# Cassandra 3.11, Filter Results by list (searching for alternatives)

Tags: cassandra, cql

I want to ask cassandra to filter its results by a list of arguments. But this is not possible on a "normal" column. Or in cassandra's words:

```
IN predicates on non-primary-key columns (access_right_id) is not yet supported
```

My table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "service"
(
    course_id       uuid,
    type            text,
    access_token    uuid,

    name_de         text,
    name_en         text,
    url             text,
    edit_right_id   uuid,
    access_right_id uuid,

    PRIMARY KEY (course_id, type, access_token)
);
```

I want to execute a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM service WHERE
course_id = :courseId
AND type = :type
AND access_right_id IN :rights
```

I am now searching for a solution to my problem. I am thinking of three possible solutions:

1. Send N times the query (maybe with a materialized view and `access_right_id` as a primary key part (clustering key))

   ```
   SELECT * FROM service WHERE
   course_id = :courseId
   AND type = :type
   AND access_right_id = :right
   ```
2. Send a generated query like this:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM service WHERE
   course_id = :courseId
   AND type = :type
   AND (access_right_id = :right1 OR access_right_id = :right2 OR access_right_id = :right ...)
   ```
3. Send a query without filtering and filter the result in code.

What do you this is best in this case? What is more cassandra "compliant"?

Thank you in advance for your input.

Comment: How many rows can it return when you just include course_id and type ?

Comment: About 20 in this case, so it is irrelevant in this case, but I have other simmilar cases in which I have more results so be expected

Comment: what is the cardinality of the `access_right_id` ? How many possible values could be there?

Comment: Dependant on the user input, in the worst case every n entry could be different. Average case should be ~4 per shard